# authentication using JWT in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm trying to build authentication using nodejs with jwt and I successfully finish the register process to register new users to mongo database but I have problem with the login and this is the login code:

```
// Login
router.post('/log', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, { password: req.body.pass })
    .exec()
    .then(function(user) {
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.pass, user.pass, (err, result) => {        
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).send('error');
        }
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign({
            email: user.email,
            _id: user._id
          },
            'secret',
            {
              expiresIn: '1h'
            });
          return res.status(200).json({
            success: 'jwt',
            token: token
          });
        }
        return res.status(401).send('error happen');
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(401).send(err);
    });
});
```

when I type in postman /log and in the body type this structured:

```
{
    "email": "bb@bbbb.bbb",
    "password": "12345",
}
```

I get this message as response in postman:

> error happen

I can't understand what's the error with code while the register worked well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the User.findone function, it tries to find the user with given email and unhashed password.

Change this line

`User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, { password: req.body.pass })`

with this:

`User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })`

Therefore you will be able to get the user and can compare the hashed passwords

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not with JWT, the problem is that `bcrypt.compare()` returned false then that is why your method does not enter the if and pass to the return with your error message.

Based on your code I can propose this:

- You have to be sure that you are storing your hash password in the
  database or the process you are doing is fine but the password you
  enter is incorrect.
- In your search method you use the plain text password as a parameter
  to find the user, in this case the password does not have to be
  stored in an insecure way that is why a password hash is used so you
  should remove that search parameter and find the user to compare
  passwords.

  `User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })`